# Tag synonym suggestion: internationalisation <- internationalization

Tags: feature-request

- tag [internationalization](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalization)
- tag [internationalisation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalisation)

I don't have high enough reputation in these tags to propose the synonym, but this seems like a no-brainer for anyone who can get it proposed/approved.

thanks!

Comment: -zation vs -sation; -zation is more common, even in UK ;) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=internationalization%2Cinternationalisation&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinternationalization%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinternationalisation%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I didn't want to impose my American spelling on the community, but nice research!!

Answer (score 1):

Done!

[image]